# Wireframe modifier messing mesh up

Tags: modifiers, wireframe

When I add in a wireframe modifier, my mesh goes bonkers. The scale is perfectly fine and the mesh's topology is fine, so why is it doing this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you upload your blend file?

Comment: I think this can be caused by very sharp angles (<5°) which tend to throw the wireframe into infinity. Please share your file or at least the part that consistently messes up :)  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I added the .blend file!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fix your mesh a bit.

You have a lot of duplicate vertices. Go to edit mode, select all and then > <kbd>M</kbd> > By DIstance

Your mesh also has uneven parts so: Add the modifier and Then, Uncheck "even" and make the thickness smaller.

[image]